# how to write xpath to extract data between two tags

Tags: xpath, tags

How can I write an xpath to extract data between two two different tags?

```
<h1>
<div>xyz</div>

#12345("<a href="www.google.com">website</a>")

</h1>
```

I want to extract `#12345` from this. Kindly guide me through this.

Comment: Do you really want to extract `#1234`, or `#12345`, or `newline newline #12345("`? "Between two tags" would be the latter.

Comment: i want to extract #12345 alone

Comment: I think you need to better define the question (if it's still relevant). If you really just want `#12345`, then the XPath expression you need is `'#12345'`. But I'm sure that's not the case. If you need to extract all text after a specific `<div>` element before the first `(`, then alecxe's answer is what you need. If you need something different, please describe.

Comment: To be more clear i need to extract anything in the place of #12345 irrespective of data type i.e., alphanumeric and special characters hope this clears.

Comment: OK, but how do you define "the place of #12345"? You said "between two tags", but that's not the actual definition, because then you would get `#12345("`. Is alecxe's answer correct? If so, you should click the checkmark to "accept" it. If not, please tell how what you need is different from his answer.

Comment: Hi i tried alex's idea n it worked sorry for delayed response

Answer (score 1):

You can get the following text sibling of the `div` tag and use [`substring-before()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before) to extract the text before the `(`:

```
substring-before(//div/following-sibling::text(), "(")
```